# Get AppName From AssocQueryString c#

Tags: c#

The following code will give me the appName from an extension.

```
   [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
      static extern uint AssocQueryString(AssocF flags, AssocStr str, string pszAssoc, string pszExtra,

[Out] StringBuilder pszOut, [In][Out] ref uint pcchOut);



      public string Get(string doctype)

      {

         uint pcchOut = 0;

         AssocQueryString(AssocF.Verify, AssocStr.FriendlyAppName, doctype, null, null, ref pcchOut);

         StringBuilder pszOut = new StringBuilder((int)pcchOut);

         AssocQueryString(AssocF.Verify, AssocStr.FriendlyAppName, doctype, null, pszOut, ref pcchOut);

         string doc = pszOut.ToString();

         return doc;

      }
```

How can I alter this to give me the AppName passing in an exe path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation mentions it is possible to pass an executable name if you set the `ASSOCF_OPEN_BYEXENAME` flag, so you would want to get the name of the executable from the path, then pass it along with this flag:

```
  public string Get(string path)
  {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        uint pcchOut = 0;

        AssocQueryString(AssocF.OpenByExeName, AssocStr.FriendlyAppName, fileName, null, null, ref pcchOut);

        StringBuilder pszOut = new StringBuilder((int)pcchOut);

        AssocQueryString(AssocF.OpenByExeName, AssocStr.FriendlyAppName, fileName, null, pszOut, ref pcchOut);

        string doc = pszOut.ToString();

        return doc;
  }
```

Link to the documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471(v=vs.85).aspx